Generating sequences using a permuted congruential generator
My question is very similar to "Generating sequences using the linear congruential generator", except for permuted congruential generators instead of LCGs.
A PCG is very similar to an LCG - it is still based on a recurrence relation of the form $X_{n+1} = (aX_n+c) \text{ mod } m $, where $X$ is the series of PCG states, $X_0$ is the initial state (seed), $a$ is an arbitrary integer constant, $c$ is an arbitrary odd integer constant, and $m$ is typically a power of two. However, a PCG adds a permutation step:
$$u = (aX_n+c) \text{ mod } 2^n$$
$$X_{n+1} = u \oplus (u \gg p)$$
where $u$ is a temporary variable, $p$ is a positive integer constant, $\oplus$ denotes bitwise xor, and $\gg$ denotes a bitwise right shift. The output of the PCG at each step is the bottom half of the state, so if the state is 64-bit in size then the PCG produces 32-bit values.
Note: proper PCGs also introduce a variable bitwise rotation step for each output, but for the purposes of this question I believe this is an unnecessary complication to analysis. A description of the rotation step is covered in the wiki article linked above if you're interested.
A pseudocode implementation of the PCG described here, with $n = 64$, would look like this:
int64 x = ...; // seed
int64 a = ...; // multiplier
int64 c = ...; // increment
int   p = ...; // permute (shift)

int32 next()
{
  x = a * x + c;
  x ^= x >> p;
  return x & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

Given any sequence of unique integers whose values are in the range of the PCG's outputs, is there always a set of parameters $(x,a,c,p)$ that produces that sequence? Presumably finding those parameters is computationally difficult, given that such a capability would be extremely effective at compression?

Hint: consider a counting argument. How many different tuples $(x,a,c,p)$ are there?

@Karl I understand that the pigeonhole principle limits the number of states when the parameters are bounded, so for fixed-size integers the total number of sequences we can represent is equal to the total number of parameter states that exist, and, if we assume that the PCG is an oracle that behaves like an ideal PRF, the probability that a state is representable is something like $2^{n-s}$ for $s>n$, where $s$ is the parameter size in bits. However, with an LCG we can concretely state that some sequences fundamentally cannot be expressed, and I'd like to know if this holds for PCGs.

@Karl More simply put, in an LCG there are unique integer sequences that cannot be produced for any values of $a$ and $c$, regardless of size; is this still the case once you add a xorshift step and turn the LCG into a PCG?
